# Issue with merge sort recusrion error using java

Tags: java, mergesort

I was following a youtube video tutorial for merge sort algorithm using java.

But I keep getting this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError 
        at merge_sort.msort(merge_sort.java:27)
```

My code :

```
public static int[] msort(int a[])
    {
        int n = a.length;
        int m = n / 2;
        int l[] = new int[m];
        int r[];
        if(n % 2 == 0) 
        {
            r = new int[m];
        }
        else
        {
            r = new int[m+1];
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            l[i] = a[i];
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < r.length; j++)
        {  
           r[j] = a[m+j];
        }
        int res[] = new int[n];
        l = msort(l);
        r = msort(r);
        res = merge(l, r);
        return res;
    }
    public static int[] merge(int l[], int r[])
    {
        int len = l.length + r.length;
        int res[] = new int[len];
        int lp = 0, rp = 0, resp = 0;
        while(lp < l.length || rp < r.length)
        {
            if(lp < l.length && rp < r.length)
            {
                if(l[lp] < r[rp])
                {
                    res[resp++] = l[lp++];
                }
                else
                {
                    res[resp++] = r[rp++];
                }
            }
            else if(lp < l.length)
            {
                res[rp++] = l[lp++]; 
            }
            else if(rp < r.length)
            {
                res[rp++] = r[rp++]; 
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are missing a stop condition. If the length of the array to be sorted < 2, you should stop the recursion:

```
public static int[] msort(int a[])
{
    if (a.length < 2) { // add this condition
        return a;
    }

    ...
}
```

Second of all, you have a typo in two array indices:

```
        else if(lp < l.length)
        {
            res[rp++] = l[lp++]; 
        }
        else if(rp < r.length)
        {
            res[rp++] = r[rp++]; 
        }
```

should be

```
        else if(lp < l.length)
        {
            res[resp++] = l[lp++]; 
        }
        else if(rp < r.length)
        {
            res[resp++] = r[rp++]; 
        }
```